# Java BinaryTree balance a tree

Tags: java, tree, binary, binary-tree

I am trying to get a binary search tree to balance.

I balance the tree after the insert method.
I hope someone here can guide me through this.

The method is balanceTheTree(...).
I did a recursive method, I don't know if it's the best solution

```
public class BinaryTreeTable<E extends Comparable<E>, T> implements Table<E, T>  {

    private Node root;

    public BinaryTreeTable() {
        this.root = new Node(null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean insert(E key, T data) {
        boolean ret;

        if (this.root.key == null) {
            Node toInsert = new Node(null, key, data);
            this.root = toInsert;
            ret = true;
        } else {
            Node father = this.seekFather(key);
            if (father == null) {
                ret = false;
            } else {
                Node toInsert = new Node(father, key, data);
                if (key.compareTo(father.key) > 0) {
                    father.rSon = toInsert;
                    ret = true;
                    balanceTheTree(toInsert);
                } else if (key.compareTo(father.key) < 0) {
                    father.lSon = toInsert;
                    ret = true;
                    balanceTheTree(toInsert);
                } else {
                    ret = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private void rightRotation(Node theN) {
        Node k2 = theN.rSon;
        theN.rSon = k2.lSon;
        k2.lSon = theN;
    }

    private void leftRotation(Node theN) {
        Node k1 = theN.lSon;
        theN.lSon = k1.rSon;
        k1.rSon = theN;
    }

    private void leftRightRotation(Node theN) {
        leftRotation(theN.rSon);
        rightRotation(theN);
    }

    private void rightLeftRotation(Node theN) {
        rightRotation(theN.lSon);
        leftRotation(theN);
    }

    private void balanceTheTree(Node theN) {
        if (theN == null) {

        } else {
            if (Math.abs(Math.subtractExact(computeH(theN.rSon), computeH(theN.lSon))) > 1) {
                System.out.println("A droite " + theN.getLabel());

                if (computeH(theN.lSon) > computeH(theN.rSon)) {
                    leftRotation(theN);
                } else {
                    leftRightRotation(theN);
                }

            } else if (Math.abs(Math.subtractExact(computeH(theN.lSon), computeH(theN.rSon))) > 1) {
                System.out.println("A gauche");

            } else {
                balanceTheTree(theN.rSon);
                balanceTheTree(theN.lSon);
            }
        }
    }

    private int computeH(Node theN) {
        int ret = 1;

        if (theN == null) {
            ret = 0;
        } else if ((theN.lSon != null) && (theN.rSon == null)) {
            ret = computeH(theN.lSon) + 1;
        } else if ((theN.lSon == null) && (theN.rSon != null)) {
            ret = computeH(theN.rSon) + 1;
        } else if ((theN.lSon != null) && (theN.rSon != null)) {
            ret = Math.max(computeH(theN.lSon), computeH(theN.rSon)) + 1;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public class Node {
        // Attributs
        private Node lSon ;
        private Node rSon ;
        private Node father ; 
        private T theValue ; 
        private E key ; 

        // Constructeur
        public Node (Node father, E key, T theValue) {
            this.father = father;
            this.key = key;
            this.theValue = theValue;
        }

        public String getLabel() {
            return String.valueOf(key);
        }

        public Node getLeft() {
            return lSon;
        }

        public Node getRight() {
            return rSon;
        }

        public Node clone() {
            return new Node(this.father, this.key, this.theValue);
        }
    }
}
```

The computeH() method allows me to know the size of a node

The insertion method works correctly.

[image: My tree]

The tree i want to balance

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTreeTable binaryTreeTable = new BinaryTreeTable();
        binaryTreeTable.insert(10, "Test");
        binaryTreeTable.insert(5, "Test");
        binaryTreeTable.insert(7, "Test");
        binaryTreeTable.insert(3, "Test");
        binaryTreeTable.insert(4, "Test");
        binaryTreeTable.insert(15, "Test");
        binaryTreeTable.insert(19, "Test");
        binaryTreeTable.insert(16, "Test");
        binaryTreeTable.insert(20, "Test");

        binaryTreeTable.showTree();
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem tho? Is your code compiling? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: My problem is for the balance, here the tree is unbalanced on 15. After balancing the nodes below vanish